# Should we be replacing the blacklist tag with blocklist to reflect current SE standards?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, meta

I came across the [blacklist](/questions/tagged/blacklist) tag in a post, and SE's moved over to calling them "blocklists". In the interests of accuracy, I'd propose creating a [blocklist](/questions/tagged/blocklist) tag, and synonymising or merging [blacklist](/questions/tagged/blacklist) with [blocklist](/questions/tagged/blocklist), which should be low impact, and simply copying over the tag wiki with edits.

Comment: You do know what happened the last time we tried to synonymize/merge tags right? Low impact and simply aren't words I'd use :P

Comment: Its better than it was! and we can take our time!

Comment: I vaguely recall issues with wikis in particular, so I would highly recommend copying them over before hitting the merge button on the tags. On the other hand... if the tag you're planning to switch to doesn't already exist, the "merge" really becomes a "rename" which is a lot simpler in a number of ways. That should just work.

Comment: I'd make the tag [blocked-keywords] so it's clearer what its purpose is.

Comment: It isn't keywords though. It is tags. A blocked keyword list would be content global

Comment: The description for the tag says, "*For questions about the list of words and phrases which are blocked from appearing in posts.*" Any other name that would be informative as to its definition without using the word "keyword"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've created the blocklist tag, and have populated the tag excerpt and wiki entries. We've formalised it a bit and wrote a slightly more 'formal' tag excerpt.

We've done a tag synonym in this case - which seemed the best option, between blacklist and blocklist.

The Blacklist tag wiki was charming, and we feel it should be documented somewhere

> Welcome to the savage lands of the block list, a barren land of words and phrases which have been barred from appearing in posts and comments across either the Stack Exchange network or individually on member sites.
>
> If a word on the list appears in your post, it may be automatically eaten up by the monster, or will block your post from being submitted.
>
> Some words on the block list, and not for their fashion sense, include:
>
> - ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓
> - ▓▓▓▓▓▓
> - ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓
>
> #### See also
>
> - [tag-blacklist](/questions/tagged/tag-blacklist)

Answer (score 4):

Yes I think this is a good change. It would also stay in line with the situation around blocked tags. There are many synonyms for [blacklist] related tags that synonymize to block(ed). For example:

[blacklist-request](/questions/tagged/blacklist-request) + [tag-blacklist-request](/questions/tagged/tag-blacklist-request) => [tag-block-request](/questions/tagged/tag-block-request)

[tag-blacklist](/questions/tagged/tag-blacklist) => [blocked-tags](/questions/tagged/blocked-tags)